# Animated sidebar briefly renders in animated state despite display state being false

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm building a sidebar in a React app which has a pretty standard slide in and slide out animation.

The functionality works fine now - the sidebar slides in and slides out based upon some Redux state, which is updated using dispatch.

However, when the page first loads, the sidebar loads up momentarily, before animating out using the slide out animation.

By default, the sidebar state is set to false - so nothing should be shown. But for whatever reason, the sidebar shows up momentarily causing some strange flashing effect.

I've been trying to play around to figure out what causes this, but can't get my head round it.

For reference, here is my 'sidebar':

```
    <div data-state={sidebarStatus} onMouseLeave={() => dispatch(hideSidebar())} className="h-90vh w-240 bg-sidebar shadow-box fixed top-5vh flex flex-col justify-start items-center 
      data-[state=true]:animate-slideIn 
      data-[state=true]:left-0 
      data-[state=false]:-left-240 
      data-[state=false]:animate-slideOut">

  { children inside here} 

</div>
```

My Redux state on page load:

```
const initialState: ApplicationState = {
    sidebar: false 
}
```

And then my slide animations:

```
        slideIn: {
          '0%': { left: '-240px' },
          '100%': { left: '-10px'}
        },
        'slideOut': {
          '0%': { left: '0px'},
          '100%': { left: '-240px', display: 'none'}
        }

        slideIn: 'slideIn 0.15s linear 1',
        slideOut: 'slideOut 0.15s linear 1'
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Feels like it should be obvious, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when the sidebar is initially rendered with `default-state=false`, `data-[state=false]:-left-240` is applied, but then `data-[state=false]:animate-slideOut` is applied, and thus plays the animation, whereby it goes from `left: 0` to `left: -240px` too.

A more straightforward approach in my opinion would be to use a `transition` and move the sidebar using `transform: translateX()` (since this does not trigger layout computations, unlike `left`):

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      spacing: {
        '240': '240px',
      },
    },
  },
};

const sidebar = document.querySelector('[data-state]');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  sidebar.dataset.state = sidebar.dataset.state === 'false';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div
  data-state=false
  class="h-90vh w-240 bg-sidebar shadow-box fixed top-5vh flex flex-col justify-start items-center 
    transition-all
    data-[state=false]:-translate-x-full
    data-[state=false]:invisible 
  ">
  Foo
</div>

<button class="mx-auto block">Toggle sidebar</button>
```